# Ionic / Angular: Listen once to EventListener

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I've implemented the [Admob Pro plugin](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro) for Ionic and want to listen to the `onAdDismiss`-EventListener. The problem I have now is that this EventListener is added to the `$scope` every time I open the view with the controller (where the EventListener is needed). How can I listen to it once and delete it afterwards?

```
myApp.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaGoogleAnalytics, $cordovaDevice, $ionicHistory, $rootScope) {
  var self = this;
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener('onAdDismiss', function(e){
      $rootScope.$broadcast("adDismissed");
    });
  }
});

myApp.controller('quizController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$cordovaAdMob', function($scope, $rootScope, $cordovaAdMob) {
   var self = this;

   this.checkAnswer = function(){ ... };

   $rootScope.$on('adDismissed', function(){
      self.checkAnswer(true);
   });
}]);
```

**EDIT**: I've tried it with `removeEventListener` but this doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try: `document.removeEventListener('onAdDismiss');`

Comment: yes, but unfortunately this doesn't work

Comment: If you have jQuery loaded you can use the $.one() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling the listener function you will be able to destroy it. As follows:

```
var adDismissedListener = $rootScope.$on('adDismissed', function(){
      self.checkAnswer(true);
      adDismissedListener(); // Will destroy the listener.
   });
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bind

With a bit of googling I found that you can also run this piece of code right before you create your listener.

```
$rootScope.$$listeners.nameOfYourEvent=[];
```